# How to swap X axis values with Y axis values in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I am working on a page that includes datatables and highcharts. I'm not sure how to show the arrows in the chart with Year column values (51.9, 12.2, 2.2, 2.5) instead of 2023 column values (ABCD, EFGH etc.. ) Not sure what I'm missing.
Here is a link to my code. I have also included the code snippet. Thanks.

https://live.datatables.net/hexuwuba/8/edit

```js
// Create chart
const chart = Highcharts.chart('demo-output', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        styledMode: true
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Staff Count Per Position'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '</b> {point.y}'
    },
    series: [
        {
            data: chartData(table)
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `plotOptions` to your chart object and set the dataLabels [format](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.format) option

```js
plotOptions: {
  series: {
      dataLabels: [{
          format: '{point.y}%',
      }]
  }
}
```

updated link: https://live.datatables.net/tenidube/1/edit

Comment: Thankyou very much. It worked!! Is it possible to add legends to this chart?

Comment: Yes... [documentation example](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/highcharts/pie-legend)